# FadeIn() breaks CSS hover functionality

Tags: jquery, css

Why does jQuery's `.fadeIn()` function break my CSS hover functionality? My div should show its menu when you hover over it. When my page shows I am going to make the menu fade in then it should have my regular hover functionality.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th1hzLbv/2/) demonstrates the problem nicely.

Why does it break my hover functionality and how can I keep both the fade in and hover functionality?

*Note* I need to keep `display: flex` to ensure the menu div doesn't wrap if its wider than its parent div.

```css
.widget {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.widget-menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.widget:hover .widget-menu {
  display: flex;
  /* used to ensure wrapping doesn't occur if the menu is wider than the widget container */
}
.widget:enabled .widget-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-menu">
    <button>Btn 1</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <p>Hover me to see menu appear. Then click the below button. Now my hovering is screwed up after the animation is complete.</p>
</div>

<br/>
<button>Fade In</button>
```

Comment: What is it you want to achieve exactly? The menu is visible when faded in, so when you hover on the text, it already shows what you like right?

Comment: @Roberrrt on page load the menu will fade in so the user knows its there. Then after the first hover and hover/mouse leave, that menu should disappear as usual. Right now thats not happening

Comment: Oh, that happens because jQuery adds an inline style to your element, overruling your hover

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the `fadeIn` with flex:

```
$('.widget-menu').css('display', 'flex').hide(); // do this on doc ready or before you call the fadeIn

$('.widget-menu').fadeIn('slow'); // fade in will now use flex instead of block
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th1hzLbv/6/)

**Update**

Sorry, thought you just wanted the `fadeIn` to work with flex.  If you want the hover to work after you have done the fadeIn, you need to remove the style from menu when you next hover

```js
var menu = $('.widget-menu');
menu.css('display', 'flex').hide();
$('body > button').click(function() {
  menu.fadeIn('slow');
});

$('.widget').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).find('.widget-menu').hide();
})
```

[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th1hzLbv/7/)

Comment: is it just me or does this not work? Its the same result as my jsfiddle. I'm on firefox.

Comment: @JakeM sorry, misunderstood your question.  See update

Answer (score 0):

It's because of jQuery's `.fadeIn()` method that adds an inline style that overrides the hover. I have updated your code with some explanation to do exactly what you want:

```
// When document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fade in the menu, to show the user it's there.
    $('.widget-menu').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Fade out the menu, like you want
        $('.widget-menu').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // Reset the inline style to not mess with the :hover
            $('.widget-menu').attr('style', '');
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JQuery runs after the CSS is loaded, so any attributes that JQuery touches will now be overridden. Instead of applying the changes to show the menu directly, try using JQuery to toggle a class that mimics the `:hover` pseudo class such as `.hover` and add that class to your html. Then use JQuery to remove the `.hover` class once the mouse enters and then leaves the area. This way JQuery doesn't touch your initial CSS and it will work as intended once the `.hover`class is removed.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating: https://jsfiddle.net/2dbr2bs3/.